# jQuery: I'm having trouble loading Adsense using jQuery in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser, adsense

```
<div id="ad-1"></div>

...

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="adsref-1">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google_ad_client="pub-...";
            google_ad_slot="...";
            google_ad_width=468;
            google_ad_height=60;
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#adsref-1').appendTo(jQuery('#ad-1'));
    });
</script>
```

This basically loads Adsense after everything else has loaded, but the ads do not show up in Internet Explorer. It works in all other major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<div style="visibility:hidden;">` instead of `display:none;`

If you don't like that because it takes up space on the page, you can add `width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;`